# Python - Execute Function After Amount of Time?

Tags: python, time

What i'm trying to do is print or execute a certain string after
certain amount of time, in case of this function it is 20 seconds,
the problem is on the second loop, sure it waits 20 seconds on first loop, 
but the second loop it no longer wait, it just keeps printing.. 
why does this happen? and how can i solve it?

```
from threading import Timer
import time

startlog = time.time()

def tess():



tm = 0
while True:
    tm += 1
    print(tm)
    tess()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Indentation seems wrong in def tess()

Comment: Any reason just using sleep(20) wouldnt work?

Comment: I wrote an answer but actually I realised I don't understand the logic. It should execute the function every 20 seconds, the timer being reset after each execution? What is `start` for?

Comment: ... but it's your question, so surely you understand what you are aiming for?

Comment: Do you need it to print out every 20 seconds or just once after 20 seconds elapsed? Because if you need an output printed out every 20 seconds perhaps a scheduler might be an easy way to do this ?

Comment: `start = time.time()` seems pointless since `start` is never used.

Comment: This is looking increasingly like a typo. `startlog` != `start`

Comment: You need to define the `global startlog` in the function

Comment: thanks guys, yes the global variable solves it, i didn't think of that.

Comment: global variables are bad practice, especially in this context. Using `threading`/`multiprocessing` is the standard way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset startlog between calls to tess that "succeed" (have passed 20 s), this code works the way you want (but is ugly because of the global variables).

```
import time

startlog = time.time()

def tess():
    global startlog
    if time.time() - 20 > startlog:
        print('its been 20 secs')
        startlog = time.time()


tm = 0
while True:
    tm += 1
    print(tm)
    tess()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I used this and it is saying that startlog is undefined

Comment: @RedgarTech on what line?

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier. I am unable to answer currently. I ran the program within my program and it didnt work as an exception handler. It had a list of errors as an exception to my program.

Comment: @RedgarTech It looks like you did not use it correctly, as "startlog" is defined in my example (see `startlog = time.time()`)

Comment: Yah it didn't work for me. It kept saying startlog was undefined.

Comment: @RedgarTech Using my **exact** code? If so, on what line?

Comment: Alone it works just fine but not in my larger program as an exception. I wanted it to just do as it does alone as an exception.

Comment: @RedgarTech So the problem is not with solution, its that you don’t understand how to use it? If I am correct, please post a new question about help instead of commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `start = time.time()` to `startlog = time.time()` and define such variable as `global` or `nonlocal`:

```
def tess():
    nonlocal startlog
    ...
        startlog = time.time()
```

Or just wait 20 secs: `time.sleep(20)`

Comment: And define the global because start is on a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your  startlog variable inside loop in tess() function. You need to replace

```
start = time.time()
```

with:

```
startlog = time.time()
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to run something for 20 seconds in the background, and then execute your function.

If this is the case, you threading / multiprocessing makes more sense.

Using [this decorator](https://github.com/urigoren/decorators4DS/blob/master/decorators4DS/timeout.py), your code could be rewritten as

```
@time_limit(20)
def will_stop_after_20_secs():
    print ("doing stuff")
    time.sleep(20)


will_stop_after_20_secs()
print ("20 seconds had passed")
```